# Restricted user app selection not working on Oreo 8.0?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-8.0-oreo

I have created a restricted profile in Samsung s3 Oreo 8.0. it seems the created app does not show up in the list of apps when trying to enabling apps for restricted user (settings >cloud and accounts> users, select restricted user).

Is this Samsung device related issue or Android os related, cause in Android 7 it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you figured it out already, but for everybody's sake. I just figured this out today.
This is a known bug in Android 8 (and still there in 8.1).
It is very irritating for parents like me and did not find a fix or patch yet.
Do no know if still there in Android 9.